# How to fetch data from API which is coming from PHP file

Tags: json, axios, fetch-api

I am trying to get data from an API but the thing is the API has PHP extension. I am quite new to this thing and I really don't understand why I am not getting the data by using `result.data`.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("stock_symbol", "PPL");

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(
        result => {
            console.log('result', result.data)

        }

    )

    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: heres the js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/78hacv9j/

Comment: you can also use fetch for that . did you give it a try?

Comment: jsfiddle updated check output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter from where you are fetching the data you are making a silly mistake, the data format is in json but you are forcibly converting it to raw text so you have to replace `result.data` with only result e.g.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("stock_symbol", "PPL");

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://dev-api.sarmaaya.pk/3.0/company_fundamentals.php", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(
        result => {
            console.log('result', result) //now works
        }
    )
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

for `request.data` to work you have to replace `response.text()` with `response.json()`

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("stock_symbol", "PPL");

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://dev-api.sarmaaya.pk/3.0/company_fundamentals.php", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
        result => {
            console.log('result', result.data) //now it works
        }
    )
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```